# Replace broken characters

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a small programm that replace strings that contains umlauts, apostrophes etc.
But sometimes I haven *broken* strings that contains for example A¶ for ü, A¼ (or Ã¼) for ö, and so on.
Is there a way to fix these strings?

I just tried to use another replace statement

```
  str = str.Replace("A¶", "ü");
  str = str.Replace("A¼", "ö");
  str = str.Replace("Ã¼", "ö");
```

But this do not work for me

Comment: Just add another `Replace` statement for the character that you're replacing? Not sure I understand what you're asking for here...

Comment: Forgot to mention that - updated my question.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error - just no match

Comment: Posted an answer below...

Comment: It's late for this but assuming that "ö" decoded as ASCII will give "A¼" then why don't you pick your list of umlauts and apostrophes (you have them for other conversions, right?) then decode each string as ASCII and replace _decoded broken string_ with _original undecoded unbroken string_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like because they are non-standard characters it is having trouble matching. You will probably have to use `Regex.Replace` and reference the Unicode value of the characters in your regex: [How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string? (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

Unicode/UTF8 reference: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Complete Unicode character set: http://www.unicode.org/charts/