# hidden space in excel

Tags: oracle, excel, erp, hidden-characters, vba

I tried almost all the methods (CLEAN,TRIM,SUBSTITUTE) trying to remove the character hiding in the beginning and the end of a text. In my case, I downloaded the bill of material report from oracle ERP and found that the item codes are a victim of hidden characters.

After so many findings, I was able to trace which character is hidden and found out that it's a question mark'?' (via VBA code in another thread) both at the front and the end. You can take this item code‭: ‭11301-21‬

If you paste the above into your excel and see its length =LEN(), you can understand my problem much better.

I need a good solution for this problem. Therefore please help!

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: are your data always like 11301-21? I mean, it's always 5 digit number - 2 digit number?

Comment: No. There are item codes of various lengths. But every item code is accompanied by a strange character. If you paste the item code in my question thread above and see its length in excel it may give 9 or 10 characters when it should be 8.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Just asking to provide you a solution, because there is a way to extract only the numbers of this item code, getting the value `1130121`. Next step would be how to assemble again the numbers as item code again, with the same estructure. Are all your item codes like number - number? I mean, is there always a - in the item code and nothing else?

Comment: Can you post several examples of item codes? Maybe we can try to fix something

Comment: ‭12-92003-53‬
‭12-..1051A607‬
‭12-1074F045‬
‭12-1070F089‬
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Gary's Student](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student), because his answer inspired me.

Also, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024107/excel-vba-remove-unicode-characters-in-a-string) for this code.

This function will clean every single char of your data, so it should work for you. You need 2 functions: 1 to clean the Unicode chars, and other one to clean your item codes_

```
        Public Function CLEAN_ITEM_CODE(ByRef ThisCell As Range) As String
    If ThisCell.Count > 1 Or ThisCell.Count < 1 Then
        CLEAN_ITEM_CODE = "Only single cells allowed"
        Exit Function
    End If


    Dim ZZ As Byte

    For ZZ = 1 To Len(ThisCell.Value) Step 1
        CLEAN_ITEM_CODE = CLEAN_ITEM_CODE & GetStrippedText(Mid(ThisCell.Value, ZZ, 1))
    Next ZZ


    End Function

    Private Function GetStrippedText(txt As String) As String
If txt = "–" Then
    GetStrippedText = "–"
Else
    Dim regEx As Object

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    regEx.Pattern = "[^\u0000-\u007F]"
    GetStrippedText = regEx.Replace(txt, "")
End If

End Function
```

And this is what i get using it as formula in Excel. Note the difference in the Len of strings:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Nice use of *Regex*

Comment: Excellent! You guys nailed it! Thank you very much. I hope this will answer the questions of many who tried standard formulas like TRIM, Clean etc. A big thanks to both of you. Peace :)

Comment: The ThisCell parameter should be `ByVal`, not `ByRef`. `ByRef` is confusing because it anticipates setting ThisCell—which you don't—with the effect of resetting the caller's variable—which is all that `ByRef` is for. Similarly for the txt parameter because in VBA `ByRef` is the default.

Comment: @TomBlodget Thx for the suggestions. Updated the code thanks to your help.

Comment: Dears, I feel this VBA code is not working after an update in the code. I couldn't get a copy of the previous code yesterday. So please restore the previous version or make the current code work.

Comment: @UmarAhmad Posted the old one from yesterday.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Please,I got another issue: Item code:  WINHY–HUJ-CONT#12RN991-01 doesn't support your formula. It gives me the result by eliminating the first (-). Could you please improve your code so that it supports all item codes and eliminates just the stubborn characters.

Comment: What would be the desired output in that case? A string 25 chars long?

Comment: Yes please. The above item code however does not have hidden chars. But I have it in my file. I need the code to clean and keep the item code as it is, rather than to change its shape.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean. *The above item code however does not have hidden chars. But I have it in my file* Without the problematic code, I cannot fix anything.

Comment: ‭WIHTG–XYH-CONT#16AR999-01‬
please take this item code to work out. it has the problem. shows 27 chars instead of 25.

Comment: It shows 26 for me, and 24 after applying formula. I get `WIHTGXYH-CONT#16AR999-01` after applying formula

Comment: You mean you want to keep the `–` ?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep the (-) please.

Comment: Perfect now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have characters that **look** like a space character, but are not.  They are UniCode 8236 & 8237.

Just replace them with a space character *(ASCII 32)*.

**EDIT#1:**

Based on the string in your post, the following VBA macro will replace UniCode characters 8236 amd 8237 with simple space characters:

```
Sub Kleanup()
Dim N1 As Long, N2 As Long
Dim Bad1 As String, Bad2 As String

N1 = 8237
Bad1 = ChrW(N1)
N2 = 8236
Bad2 = ChrW(N2)

Cells.Replace what:=Bad1, replacement:=" ", lookat:=xlPart
Cells.Replace what:=Bad2, replacement:=" ", lookat:=xlPart

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @UmarAhmad  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: The space character is U+0020—VBA doesn't use ASCII.