# The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request when calling web service from a windows application

Tags: c#, web-services, client

I have a web service that send a string as input parameter,do some functions on it and return a result. It works perfectly, when I debug it and call it inside a browser but when I call it from another application it returns the Error "The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request ". As 400 errors are errors from client side I could not find out which is making this problem to me!!!

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Application that works is probably using a cookie.  If you delete cookies from IE history manually the working code will stop working.  To resolve issue I normally delete cookies and then capture with sniffer like wireshark or fiddler the IE that works.  Then modify my c# application to look like working IE by adding missing headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, As I told before Error 400 is a client side Error and my problem did not happen on Browsers but on calling from an application.

The problem was because of the string that I was sending to web service contains non-ASCII characters so It could not return the correct result. With the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c) I removed non-ASCII characters and then send it to web service again and now it works perfectly.