# Remove certain Unicode (garbage) JSON characters

Tags: c#, json, regex

I'm reading data from a file, and sometimes the file contains funky stuff, like:

```
"ä‰ŒÄ€áœŠÂ»ç‰ç•‡ï¼ƒè¸²æœ€ä²’Bíœë¨¿ä„€å•²ï²ä‹¾é¥˜BéŒé“‡ä„€â²ä‹¾â¢"
```

I need to strip/replace these characters as JSON has no idea what to do with them.

They aren't control characters (I think), so my current regex of

`Regex.Replace(value, @"\p{C}+", string.Empty);`

Isn't catching them.

A lot of these strings read in are going to be long, upwards of256 characters, so I'd rather not loop through each char checking it.

Is there a simple solution to this?  I'm thinking regular expressions would solve it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It looks like you're reading the file using the wrong encoding.

Comment: This is what I thought, but 99% of the strings read are valid, these happen maybe one in every 1000 reads.  It's more than likely data corruption, as these are the remnants of log files.

Comment: If you look, that's the answer that I found the regex I'm using in :)

Comment: When you encounter garbage data like this, is it the entire file, or just parts of a file?  Also, I think your title is inaccurate, as these are printable characters.

Comment: Please define the chars you want to remove. It is also a good idea to paste the text as text to the question itself. If you want to only keep printable ASCII, try `Regex.Replace(s, "[^ -~]+", "")`

Comment: It's just parts of the file, these are remnants of old, circular log files.  Good point, I'll update the title.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/E5h1LS/1

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.  I'll give that a go.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good plan to turn someone's text data into garbage and then throw some of the garbage out in hopes of retaining some of the original data. Can you show what might be the problem upstream?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is ASCII then you could do:

```
Regex.Replace(value, @"[^\x00-\x7F]+", string.Empty);
```

and if all you want are the "normal" ASCII characters, you could do:

```
Regex.Replace(value, @"[^\x20-\x7E]+", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/123340/3832970 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018166/3832970. No need to duplicate SO contents.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew then mark this as a duplicate of that question?

Comment: It is already closed.