# How to remove non-ascii characters in CsvHelper

Tags: csvhelper

Is there a way to remove non-ascii characters with configuration in `CsvHelper` instead of writing the conversion in application code?

I saved an Excel to CSV and found some values like `AbsMarketValue�������������` and I would like to get rid of the non-ASCII characters.

`csv.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII` did not work.

With reference to [How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string? (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

```
string s = "søme string";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);
```

The above approach works for me but I want to avoid this since this requires me to add this type of code in application for any text field.

I tried to do this in the conversion map but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a type converter, you could have all string properties only output ASCII characters.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id,Name\n1,AbsMarketValue�������������"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new AsciiOnlyConverter());
        
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class AsciiOnlyConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var ascii = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);
        
        return base.ConvertFromString(ascii, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so  much @David Specht